# GPG Encryption in a Ruby App

Tags: ruby, gnupg

I would like to encrypt a zip file with gpg encryption in a ruby app.

I have taken a look at the gpgme gem but it doesn't have any clear examples on how to encrypt a file.

In order to encrypt a file I will have the public key. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a command line and the program `gpg`?

If so, you can just use a system call in Ruby.

```
system("gpg --option1 arg1 --option2 arg2")
```

or

```
system("gpg", "--option1", arg1, "--option2", arg2)
```

Check out the [documentation for `Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system).